# Linq to objects C# nested class

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

```
public class parent
{
    public string abc { get; set; }
    public childclass pos { get; set; }
}

public class childclass
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I am currently reading the collection of parent class

```
var obj =
(from dia in parent
    select new
    {
        abc = dia.abc,
        pos = new childclass()
        {
            value = dia.pos.value
        },
    })
.ToList();
```

how do I read the nested class childclass using linq to object , this piece is not working

```
pos = new childclass()
{
    Value = dia.pos.Value
},
```

Please advise

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: I don't get it, what you wanna to do?
Create childclass object for each parent instance?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: @Exsaliver Currently it appears to be making a deep copy of the collection of parent objects, but I don't know if that's intentional or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly, I think your problem is case sensitive

Classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Abc { get; set; }

    public Childclass Pos { get; set; }
}

public class Childclass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Use:

```
var parent = new List<Parent> {                
    new Parent { Abc = "abc1", Pos = new Childclass { Value = "Value1" } },
    new Parent { Abc = "abc2", Pos = new Childclass { Value = "Value2" } }
};

var obj =(from dia in parent select new {
                abc = dia.Abc,
                pos = new Childclass()
                {
                    Value = dia.Pos.Value
                },
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is case-sensitive.  The `value` field in your class `childClass` has a lower-case 'v'.  Your LINQ statement is referencing it using an upper-case 'V'.

Try the following code:

```
var obj = (from dia in parent
            select new
            {
                abc = dia.abc,
                pos = new childclass()
                {
                    value = dia.pos.value // 'Value' has been changed to 'value'
                },
            }).ToList();
```

Here is a test I ran to verify that the updated LINQ statement works:

```
var parents = new List<parent>()
{
    new parent{abc = "abc", pos = new childclass{ value = "value" }}
};
var obj =
            (from dia in parents // changed to 'parents' to match my variable above
            select new
            {
                abc = dia.abc,
                pos = new childclass()
                {
                    value = dia.pos.value
                },
            }).ToList();

foreach (var par in obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(par);
}
```

The resulting output was:

`"{ abc = abc, pos = ProgrammingTestBed.Program+childclass }"`

Comment: still not the underlying problem though, just a typo.

Comment: Well it actually compiles fine for me when I make that change.

Comment: Well, there's also a missing semi-colon in the definition of `parent` (I've edited the OP since though).  Having said that, the fundamental design of the query seems...off, but before fixing it we'd need to know what the asker is trying to do.

Comment: I am passing a list of parent , it is reading abc fine but not able to read nested class, getting error " cannot convert class childclass to string"

Comment: True, I updated the definition of `parent` when I was trying to compile it and forget to mention that.  Good catch.